# GeoServer: Server Status Tabs are not accessible

Tags: geoserver, tomcat

I have updated GeoServer, Java and Tomcat to the newer versions. Configuraton is the following:

[image]

After that I can't access Server Status Tabs. Just first one is accessible. Nothing happens when I click on Modules, System Status and JVM Console tabs.

[image]

Before updating this server, I have successfully update 2 other servers and didn't encounter this issue. Tried it uninstall and come back to the previous versions and install again. Issue remains.

What can be the problem?

Comment: hard to say - what is different about this server? proxy? firewall? does the log file say anything?